# How to prepend an element to all classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function called **adName** that I am trying to make prepend a **span** tag with text inside the **code** element with a class **obj**. The problem is that I keep getting errors, and the **span** tag isn't inside the **code** tag, instead it is right beside it. Also, I'm trying to make all the **code** tags that have class of **obj** have **span** tags. But in my code, the last class has the **span** tag of 'Object':

So there are 3 objects `<code class="obj">poke1</code>`, `<code class="obj">poke2</code>` and `pokeAb`, and there is a constructor called Pokemon. Poke1&2 has properties of name, type, and attack. When I activate the call method with pokeAb's method called `fight`, and I put one of the poke's (1 or 2) inside the parenthesis, it will grab the properties of the object and print out something depending on what poke I called.

```
function adName(clas, name, color, back) {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName(clas);
  var b = document.createTextNode(name);
  var c = document.createElement('span').appendChild(b);
  var d = document.querySelectorAll('code');

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    a[i].parentNode.insertBefore(c, a[i]);
    a[i].style.background = back;
    a[i].style.color = color;
  }
}

adName('obj','Object:','#003366','#99ccff');
```

Comment: Do you want to add the span before the code tag or inside the code tag before the code inner html?

Comment: I want the span tag to be inside of the code tag that has the class of obj

Answer (score 2):

When you use `a[i].parentNode`, you are reaching the `p` element and adding the `span` to a place before code element. You should do like this:

```
function adName(clas, name, color, back) {
var a = document.getElementsByClassName(clas);
var b = document.createTextNode(name);
var c = document.createElement('span');
c.appendChild(b);
var d = document.querySelectorAll('code');

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    a[i].innerHTML = c.outerHTML + a[i].innerHTML;
    a[i].style.background = back;
    a[i].style.color = color;
  }
}

adName('obj','Object:','#003366','#99ccff');
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1z1bd8yj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the span element in the loop. Here's how your `adName` function should look

```
function adName(clas, name, color, back) {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName(clas);
  var b, c;

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    b = document.createTextNode(name);
    c = document.createElement('span');
    c.appendChild(b);

    a[i].insertBefore(c, a[i].childNodes[0]);
    a[i].style.background = back;
    a[i].style.color = color;
  }
}
```

See this pen for a working solution http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNzBJL?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you consider to use jQuery?

Your function would be much cleaner:

```
function adName(clas, name, color, back) {
  $("." + clas).prepend($("<span/>").html(name));
  $("." + clas).css("background-color", back).css("color", color);
}
```

but if you would like to keep pure javascript:

```
function adName2(clas, name, color, back) {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName(clas);

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    a[i].innerHTML = name + a[i].innerHTML;
    a[i].style.background = back;
    a[i].style.color = color;
  }
}
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Zq42iRBnijmf2NQ43LfA?p=preview

Comment: Note: your `innerHTML` solution will break possible event listeners of child elements. I think promoting jQuery for "much cleaner" solutions is not good for beginners (unless some beginner tries to reinvent the whee...jQuery).

Comment: So feel free to write a better answer :)